# Getting numbers behind decimal point

Tags: c#, math, decimal, digit

I'm currently developing in C# and I'm trying get a digit from a `float` value and store it into an `int`. For example:

```
float f = 0.04;
```

I want `int r = 4;`

Is there a way to do this? I want to be able to `switch(r)`.

Comment: What's the rule? Do you want the second digit, the last significant digit, the fractional part as hundredths, or something else?

Comment: once you have `r=4`, how do you get back to `f=0.04`?

Comment: It should be mentioned that floats don't have infinite precision, so the "last significant digit" in float is undefined for many values.

Answer (score 4):

In the case given above, of `f = 0.04` and a result of `r=4`. 

You could multiply by `10` until `f > 0` , which is necessary if f `!=0`.

Then, to obtain `r = 4` you could cast to an integer.

```
int r = (int)f;
```

That should get the trick done.

Comment: I wrote a function but to do that but it is returning a zero and idk why. I used the same float as above, f = 0.04F to test it. Here it is <pre> <code> public int getNonZeroDigit(float f)
        {
            int result = 0;
            bool done = false;

            while (!done)
            {
                f = f * 10; 

                if (f > 0)
                {
                    done = true; 
                }
            }

            result = (int)f;
            return result;
        }</code> </pre>

Comment: @MarkVanDuyne: You should surround inline code in backquotes. More to the point, your attempts to solve the problem should appear in the question.

Comment: @MarkVanDuyne The code you've posted is not really clear. Did you know that you may post codes at [Gist](http://gist.github.com/) as well? Have a great day :)

Comment: I appologize profusely!!! it should be f >=1 the reason this is is when the compiler casts from a float to an integer it just drops all of the decimal points (also known as "floor"ing). So f>=1 should suit your cause much better If you are curious this process is called narrowing, since there is data lost in the process of the cast. Narrowing includes casting from: double -> long int -> short int -> char -> bool The opposite is called Widening, as no data is lost in the cast: bool -> char -> short int -> long int -> double Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Although I do not really know how did you manage to set a `float` of type `struct` to `0.04` without appending the `F` character to the end of the value, this is possible!

I'd recommend you at this point to convert the number containing the decimal point to a string first. Then, you may use `Int32.Parse(string s)` to convert it to `int` after obtaining the numbers after the decimal point

**Example**

```
private Int32 GetDecimals(float n)
{
    string s = n.ToString("#.#########", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //Convert the value to string
    return Int32.Parse(s.Substring(s.IndexOf(".") + 1)); //Return what's after the decimal point from the value as Int
}
```

You may then use `GetDecimals(float n)` to get the value after the decimal point from a `float`.

**Example**

```
float f = 0.04F; //Initialize a new float of name f
int r = 0; //Initialize a new int of name r
r = GetDecimals(f); //Set r to 4
```

**Notice:** You may change `Int32` within `GetDecimals` with your desired output if you would like to get the values after the decimal points in an output that is any other struct than `int`

**Notice:** You may change `float` in `GetDecimals(float n)` with the desired struct you would like to convert if you would like to use `GetDecimals` to convert other struct types than `float`.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)